# Supporting OData Count when using Data Access Layer

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

My ASP.NET 5 API site uses data access layers (Managers, Services, Stores, etc.) to pull data from databases. These layers are called from the Controllers and return `IActionResult` to the caller. These layers allow us to add business rules and other "back end" logic to the queries that are executed.

When ASP.NET OData is added, everything works without issue **except** the `$count` parameter. This is because, under normal circumstances, an `IQueryable<T>` is returned from the controller which allows OData to modify the query based on incoming query parameters and execute it. This execution includes (*most likely*) a second execution of the query without `$skip` and `$top` added so the total number of rows can be included in the result set.

However, because my DAL is returning an `IEnumerable<T>` (after the query is **already** executed), the OData service (?? ActionFilter??) generates an **inaccurate** count based on the collection it was given.

*Note that I am using `ODataQueryOptions<T>` in the controller to exclude the filter, skip, and top parameters so they can be passed down to the different layers of data access.*

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase {

   [EnableQuery()]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetMyStuff(ODataQueryOptions<Stuff> options) {
      // Extract filter, skip, top from ODataQueryOptions

      var x = await _manager.GetStuff(filter, skip, top);

      var count = await _manager.GetCountOfStuff(filter);
      // How do I let OData know what the count value is???

      return Ok(x);
   }

}
}
```

Assuming that I generate the count value (using my DAL), my question ultimately becomes

How can I let OData **know** what that value is instead of **it** trying to figure it out?

Comment: Have you tried to use a `PageResult` instead an `IActionResult` ?

`new PageResult<SomeObject>(x, Request.ODataProperties().NextLink, (Int64)count);`

Comment: I was trying to stay consistent with `IActionResult` so I can do things like `return OK(xyz)` or `return NotFound()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out myself. Unsure when it was added (I do not recall seeing this years ago when I first started playing with MS OData libraries) but there is an extension method called `ODataFeature()` off of the `Request` object that allows you to set some response values.

My code ended up looking like

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase {

   [EnableQuery()]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetMyStuff(ODataQueryOptions<Stuff> options) {
      // Extract filter, skip, top from ODataQueryOptions

      var x = await _manager.GetStuff(filter, skip, top);

      // ****************************************************
      // NEW code to optional inject $count when needed

      if (options.Count?.Value == true) {
         Request.ODataFeature().TotalCount = await _manager.GetCountOfStuff(filter);
      }

      // ****************************************************

      return Ok(x);
   }

}
```